# How can I specify the source for a member name in a WinForms collections editor?

Tags: c#, winforms

Is it possible to change the property used to source the member name in the collections editor seen below?

[image: Image of the collections editor]

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
[Serializable] // Class is also bin serialised
public class SocialPolicy
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The ID of the social policy
    /// </summary>
    [Description("The ID of the social policy")]
    [DisplayName("ID"), Browsable(true), Category("General")]
    [XmlElement("ID")]
    public string ID { get; set; } = "POLICY_NULL";

    /// <summary>
    /// The name of the social policy in a display ready format
    /// </summary>
    [Browsable(false)]
    [XmlIgnore]
    public string Name { get; set; } = "Null";

    /// <summary>
    /// The Tree ID of the social policy
    /// </summary>
    [Description("The Tree ID of the social policy")]
    [DisplayName("TreeID"), Browsable(true), Category("General")]
    [XmlElement("TreeID")]
    public string TreeID { get; set; } = "POLICYTREE_NULL";

    ...
}
```

Currently it is sourcing its name from the default, the Name property which is always "Null" in my editor, but I would rather it source it from ID. I have been searching for any decorations I could use to change it but haven't been able to find any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class that holds the list of SocialPolicy can provide that by using a custom version of the [CollectionEditor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.collectioneditor(v=vs.110).aspx) and overriding the GetDisplayText function:

```
public class Test {

  [Editor(typeof(TestEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
  public List<SocialPolicy> Policies { get; }

  public Test() {
    this.Policies = new List<SocialPolicy>();
    this.Policies.Add(new SocialPolicy());
  }

  public class TestEditor : CollectionEditor {
    public TestEditor(Type type)
        : base(type) {
    }

    protected override string GetDisplayText(object value) {
      if (value is SocialPolicy) {
        return ((SocialPolicy)value).ID;
      } else {
        return value.ToString();
      }
    }
  }
}
```